# “Standard kinetic energy term of nonrelativistic quantum mechanics” $[\mathbf p\cdot \mathbf A + \mathbf A \cdot \mathbf p]$

Tags: electromagnetism, energy

On page 187 of Peskin and Schroeder, a certain term in an expression for the amplitude of an electron scattering from a classical magnetic vector potential is identified with “the contribution of the operator $[\mathbf p\cdot \mathbf A + \mathbf A \cdot \mathbf p]$ in the standard kinetic energy term of nonrelativistic quantum mechanics.

How does this operator arise in nonrelativistic quantum mechanics and why is it a kinetic energy term?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Hamiltonian of a non-relativistic, charged particle in a magnetic field with vector potential $A$ and scalar potential $\phi$ is
$$ H = \frac{1}{2m}(p - qA)^2 + q\phi$$
where $p$ is the *canonical* momentum (this is an elementary example for a case where canonical and kinematic momentum differ), and $p-qA$ is the kinematic momentum, i.e. the first summand is just kinetic energy $\frac{1}{2m}p_\text{kin}^2$. If you resolve the square, you of course get a term proportional to $p\cdot A + A\cdot p$.